# Bad: git cloning problems

Tags: git, github, npm, git-clone, cloning

After cloning when i try to install it shows the following warnings and is unable to install. I clonned this very repo once before and it cloned successfully. But after that i had uninstalled git and deleted all the cloned contents. Now when I try to clone again I face several errs and warnings.

```
  C:\Users\91830>git clone https://github.com/example/example.git

Cloning into 'example'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 51, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (51/51), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (43/43), done.
Receiving objects:  76% (39/51), 7.79 MiB | 2.18 MiB/sreused 0 eceiving objects:
  72% (37/51), 7.79 MiB | 2.18 MiB/s
Receiving objects: 100% (51/51), 9.39 MiB | 2.35 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8), done.
C:\Users\91830>npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
'C:\Users\91830\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
 'C:\Users\91830\package.json'
npm WARN 91830 No description
npm WARN 91830 No repository field.
npm WARN 91830 No README data
npm WARN 91830 No license field.
up to date in 0.795s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: The clone seems to be successful the issue seems to be with your `npm`. You need to be in the repo folder to run. See how to resolve below.

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem with git? Also, the warnings are pretty clear that the package.json is missing some fields that npm would prefer to have.

Comment: The issue exsist in the npm install. Instead of npm install can you try `npm ci` and check whether you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue stems not from `git clone` (that was successful) but that you attempted `npm install` one directory above. `git clone` by default creates a folder. There should be a folder called Online-shopping-platform.

Try:

```
cd Online-shopping-platform
npm install
```

Note that this is explicitly stated in the repo:

> To get the code on your machine: Firstly, clone the repo on your machine. After cloning, using command line, **move to that repo** and run the following commands:
>
> npm install
>
> npm start